# Localization of attribute values in .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, localization, attributes, internationalization

How can I **localize/internationalize** attribute values in .NET?

My specific example is for [ASP.NET web parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpart.aspx) such as WebDisplayName, WebDescription, etc. where I inherit from the base class that uses these attributes.

Also, is there any difference to doing this with attributes declared in my own classes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you had a look at [Localizing the Property Grid](http://www.morganskinner.com/Articles/LocalizedPropertyGrid/)?

This seems pretty much the same thing, except you're inheriting from `WebDescriptionAttribute` (et al) instead of `DescriptionAttribute`.  All of the important properties in the `Web` classes, like `Description`, are still overridable.

The example on that page calls out to a static `SR` class, which retrieves string resources from a specific type.  If you need to support multiple languages *at the same time* - and obviously take a minor performance hit in the process - then you would have to adjust the attribute itself to take the `Type` of the resource you expect, and use the [appropriate constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1twa172%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for the `ResourceManager` class.

I can go into more detail if you want to expand a little on the intended uses.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer:

[Localization of DisplayNameAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356464/localization-of-displaynameattribute/357008#357008)

You would have to add attributes to your derived classes to override the ones on the base classes.