# ASP.NET MVC - Local Resource Issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, globalization, resx

I am having an issue when attempting to override the DisplayNameAttribute in ASP.NET MVC to provide a localized string. The code itself is straightforward and similar to that in another Stackoverflow post [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356464/localization-of-displaynameattribute)

The code works for global resources but not so well for local resources. I have a registration screen and used the Visual Studio "Generate Local Resource" command to create my local resource file. The generated file is named Registration.aspx.resx and the App_LocalResources folder is created relative to the actual Registration.aspx page - as one would expect.

However, when I attempt to get the localized string using:

`ResourceManager.GetString(resourceKey)`

I receive the following error message.

> Could not find any resources
>   appropriate for the specified culture
>   or the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "FullAssemblyName.Views.Account.App_LocalResources.Registration_aspx.resources"
>   was correctly embedded or linked into
>   assembly "FullAssemblyName" at compile
>   time, or that all the satellite
>   assemblies required are loadable and
>   fully signed.

Using reflector, I can see that the file is actually Registration.aspx.resources and not Registration_aspx.resources - the underscore/period being the subtle difference

> FullAssemblyName.Views.Account.App_LocalResources.Registration.aspx.resources

I have toyed with the code quite a bit but no matter what I do, the file being requested is always different than that copiled in  the assembly. For instance, if i rename Registration_aspx (in the generated Registration.aspx.designer.cs class i get the same error but this time the path is "...App_LocalResources.Registrationaspx.resources"

Has anyone run into this? Is there any way I can ensure that the resource found in my assembly has this underscore?!?!?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try Michael K. Campbell solution [link text](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/aspnet22/ASP-NET-MVC-Localization.aspx). It worked fine form me in localizing my project.