# Localize DisplayNameAttributes in ActionFilter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, actionfilterattribute, displayattribute

Is it possible to access the DisplayNameAttributes that are used on my ViewData.Model so I can Localize them before sending them to the view?
Something like this:

```
Public Void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext: filterContext) {
  foreach (DisplayNameAttribute attr in filterContext...) {
    attr.TheValue = AppMessages.GetLocazation(attr.TheValue);
  }
}
```

What I'm missing is how to access the attributes. Is this possible at all?

P.S: We're using vb.net at my job and it's infiltrating my brain. So apologies if my C# is a tad off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't change attribute values at runtime.**  In the best case this will be a no-op (as you'll be operating on *copies* of the attribute instances); in the worst case this will lead to race conditions in your code.  Always treat attribute instances as immutable.

If you need to localize [DisplayName], subclass it and override the virtual DisplayName property.  See [Localization of DisplayNameAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356464/localization-of-displaynameattribute) for an example of how to do this.

Comment: It's sad MS didn't go the extra mile, but I think this is what I'll be doing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Yes, you can access this.](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html)