# Bind to an object's attribute from XAML in .net 4.5

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, attributes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access DisplayName in xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154050/access-displayname-in-xaml)

Is there a standard way in XAML to bind to an attribute of an object?  I know this is a similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154050/access-displayname-in-xaml) and that I can create a MarkupExtension or use a Converter.  I'm just wondering if there's some built in markup or native support in .net 4.5.

i.e.

```
// Some class with an Attribute:

[Description("A description")]
class Foo
{
}

// XAML - DataContext is a Foo object
<UserControl DataContext="{StaticResource myFoo}"  
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ?Description?}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Yeah that's why I reference that post.  I just thought since it was a year old there might be a change in .net 4.5 or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native support for binding to an attributes. You should write your own markup extension.

Answer (score 2):

No; it needs to be a an explicit `Property` or implicitly inherited via the `DataContext`, ie...`{Binding}`.