# WPF DataGrid bind DataGridTextColumn to DisplayNameAttribute

Tags: wpf

I have binding to:

```
[DisplayName("שם יצרן")]
public string SHEM_YATZRAN { get; set; }

<toolkit:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="shemYatzranColumn"
    Binding="{Binding SHEM_YATZRAN}"
    Header="שם יצרן" />
```

I want to bind the Header to the DisplayName attribute
how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access DisplayName in xaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154050/access-displayname-in-xaml)

Comment: not worked for me. i need it on the datagrid header

Comment: Why it does not work?

Comment: <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, ConverterParameter=ExistingProducts.MISPAR_ZIHUY_LAKOACH, Converter={StaticResource displayNameConverter}}"/> the compiler says he cannot convert textblock to enum..

Comment: here what i have tried: 
<toolkit:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="IdColumn"
     Binding="{Binding MISPAR_ZIHUY_LAKOACH}">
                    <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, ConverterParameter=MISPAR_ZIHUY_LAKOACH, Converter={StaticResource displayNameConverter}}"/>
                    </toolkit:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                </toolkit:DataGridTextColumn>

Comment: Try ConverterParameter="MISPAR_ZIHUY_LAKOACH"