# Localize WPF PropertyGrid control from Denis Vuyka

Tags: wpf, localization, propertygrid

I found [this](https://github.com/DenisVuyka/WPG/wiki)
property control for WPF from Denis Vuyka, which does just what I want.

The only problem is in localizing categories, display names and descriptions.

It uses attributes like these:

```
[Category("This is the category")]
[DisplayName("This is the display name")]
[Description("This is the description")]
public int littleTest { get; set; }
```

Does anybody know how I can get these strings into a resx file or the xaml file to be able to use a translation tool?

The attributes want to have constants so I can't get the strings via resource manager.

Is there another way to have the PropertyGrid use localized strings?

Comment: See this question for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356464/localization-of-displaynameattribute