# Setting a variable - constructor/get/set C#

Tags: c#, constructor

i haven programmed in a while so i forgot something.

ive got a "Kunde" class. with some variables:

```
class Kunde
{
    private string _navn;
    private string _adresse;
    private int _postnr;
    private string _by;
    private int _telefonnr;
    private int _mobil;
    private string _email;
    private string _land;
    private string _oplysning;
    private int _kundenr;
    //Erhverv:
    private int _cvr;
    private string _firmanavn;
    private string _kontaktperson;

    //Tom konstruktør
    public Kunde()
    {
    }

    //privat
    public Kunde(string navn, string adresse, int postnr, string by, int telefonnr, int mobil, string email, string land, string oplysning, int kundenr)
    {
        _navn = navn;
        _adresse = adresse;
        _postnr = postnr;
        _by = by;
        _telefonnr = telefonnr;
        _mobil = mobil;
        _email = email;
        _land = land;
        _oplysning = oplysning;
        _kundenr = kundenr;
    }
}
```

}

my question is.. ive got a winform with some text fields, but not every field has to be filled with data..

should a make a get/set on every variable to be able to set the variable from another class - or a constructor for each option?

whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just provide a Get and optionally a Set accessor for each member.

You'll have to pick some form of DataBinding + Validation to work from your Form. But a Customer class has its own design and its own logic.

Comment: Thansk!

well databinding - do you have a reference?

Comment: isen't databinding only for ASP.net?

Comment: databinding is for ASP.Net, WinForms and WPF as well

Comment: is data-binding really necessary ?

Comment: Mathias: when you copy the data from textbox to property then that too is a form of databinding.

Answer (score 2):

In C# 4.0, you can specify values for properties when calling a constructor.

```
var kunde = new Kunde() 
{
    Navn = navn,
    Adresse = adresse,
    // all your properties
};
```

Create `get`/`set` accessors for each of your fields and then you can specify whichever properties you want to set as above.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better keep default constructor only and create public property for each data you need to read or set.

You may keep your constructor with parameters - but only with those that are really mandatory to be filled for each of your Kunde-n.

If you plan to bind your Kunde object-s directly to some BindingSource and display them e.g. in some sort of grid/list and/or treeview you may also consider implementing some of the related interfaces: System.ComponentModel.IdataErrorInfo; System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged;

and you may cosider apply Attribute-s to your public properties - such as System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute; - it can define fixed name of headers in the DataGrid or[it might be localized for different languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356464/localization-of-displaynameattribute)

Comment: i need to put my kunde objects in a list.. and then show the list in somekind of table yeah.. 

i might take a look at the displaynameattribute - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`public string Adresse { get; private set; }` etc. and you have an automatic variable which is read-only except inside the class.