# How do I localize data annotations messages in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Localization of DisplayNameAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356464/localization-of-displaynameattribute)

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo
{

    [DisplayName("??")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

What is the best solution for localising this property?

Comment: Take a look at [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356464/localization-of-displaynameattribute)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use GlobalResources, check the example below

**Resource1.resx**

|Name|Name|

|....|....|

|....|....|

**Resource1.da.DK**

|Name|Navn|

|....|....|

|....|....|

```
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource1), ErrorMessageResourceName  = "Name")]
    public virtual string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```