# name constants from embedded resources for dataannotation use in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, data-annotations, embedded-resource

When I create an embedded resource file like `MyResources.resx`, I can access the values easily from code (or in asp.net views and so on) using the generated property `MyResources.MyLabel1` for example. If I want to use it as an data annotation, i write something like this:

```
[Display(Name = "MyLabel1", ResourceType = typeof(MyResources))]
public string SomeInput { get; set; }
```

Obviously "MyLabel1" is now a hard-coded string which can cause problems when the resource is modified and the name is changed or removed and so on.

I've seen people using constants like this:

```
public const string MyLabel1 = "MyLabel1";
```

and changing the data annotation to something like this:

```
[Display(Name = MyConstants.MyLabel1, ResourceType = typeof(MyResources))]
public string SomeInput { get; set; }
```

You still have to maintain this hard-coded string, though.

So my question is: Can I have those name constants generated somehow? using a custom T4 template or a custom resource manager or anything already existing? So that changing or removing the label would lead to compile errors...

Comment: Similar question been asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356464/localization-of-displaynameattribute. Here is a T4 script that generates constants http://stackoverflow.com/a/3311128/1314859.