# MVC Validation message internationalization

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, internationalization

For example, I would like this default ASP.NET MVC 4 validation message: `The value 'qsdqsdqs' is not valid for Montant` to be displayed in french.

I found this package http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.fr/ and installed it but how do I get it to work ?

I added `<globalization culture="fr-FR" uiCulture="auto:fr" />` to web.config and referenced the dll but the message is still in english

Comment: I found the answer: the corect syntax is <globalization culture="fr-FR" uiCulture="fr" />

Comment: Actually it works when validating a numeric property but not when using the 'RequiredAttribute' :/

Answer (score 11):

First of all you should keep your messages in Resources files like that:

```
Resources/ErrorMessages.resx // default messages
Resources/ErrorMessages.fr.resx // for french
```

On server side it's vary easy, and you can do it by adding an attribute to your model. Do it like that:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ErrorMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldRequired")]
```

where **"FieldRequired"** is one of the fields in **Resources.ErrorMessages**

The tricky part is when you want the client side validation to work as well. Than you have to create your own attribute class which **extends** one of the **attributes** and also **implements IClientValidatable**.

You to it like that:

```
public class CustomRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        {
            return String.Format(ErrorMessages.FieldRequired, name);
        } 

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            var rule = new ModelClientValidationRequiredRule(String.Format(ErrorMessages.FieldRequired, metadata.DisplayName));
            return new[] { rule };
        }
    }
```

From now on you use CustomRequired instead of Required in your models. You also don't have to specify the message each time.

**EDIT**

Now I've seen your comment on SynerCoder's answer - that you don't want to translate messages yourself. Well I don't think it's the right approach. Even if you find something that will translate the standard messages for you it won't translate any custom messages, so you'll probably end up mixing 2 approaches. This usually leads to magic errors you don't know how to bite. I strongly suggest you do the translations yourself (it's not much to do - something like 20 or so?). The benefit will be a flexible solution with no unexpected errors.

Comment: I have used provided solution within a MVC 5 solution using a custom generated ResourceProvider (strongly-typed generated from a table) and client side validation messages are also translated (no IClientValidatable trick seems to be required). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually using ResX Manager.
Visual Studio menu Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> search for "resx" in Online tools.

With its helpers all my strings are accessed like "Res.SomeTranslatedString".
Now with credits to everybody above, let's translate a registration viewmodel message for a boolean property to check if user accepted terms and conditions. With the above tool i have put the string into `Res.YouMustAcceptTermsAndConditions`. Then we modify the viewmodel code:

Was:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage = "You must accept terms and conditions.")]
    [Display(Name = "Agree to terms.")]
    public bool AgreeTerms { get; set; }
```

Became:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Res), ErrorMessageResourceName = "YouMustAcceptTermsAndConditions")]
    [Display(Name = "Agree to terms.")]
    public bool AgreeTerms { get; set; }
```

Now you see that we have the [Display] still untranslated.. The solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3877154/7149454