# How can avoid use a hardcode string in ErrorMessage with DataAnnotations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, validation

My question is the following:

Is there any chance to avoid hardocode the string to set the ErrorMessage=".."?

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="My message harcoded")]

public int ID { get; set; }
```

I can't use a method like this, because ErrorMessage only accept a const.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = GetErrorMessage())]

public int ID { get; set; }
```

Comment: You can use constants(SomeClass.ConstField), other than that **no**

Comment: You can potentially do something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356464/localization-of-displaynameattribute (subclassing Required)

Comment: You can use localization resource files. [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ModelValidation), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MessageKey")]

Comment: Really! thanks all for your reply, I really don´t know the ErrorMessageResourceType.