# Internationalization in asp.net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What is the correct way to use internationalization in a Asp.net 5 MVC project ?

If I try to decorate my model classes with `DisplayName` for example, Visual Studio gives me an error:

`Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DisplayName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   MyProject.DNX Core 5.0  C:\Users\paulo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyProject\src\MyProject\Models\Post.cs 20`

I can´t even create a resource file in this type of project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Localization of DisplayNameAttribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356464/localization-of-displaynameattribute)

Comment: Asp.net 5 does not introduce new ways to do this? That was a 2010 post.

Answer (score -1):

You need to reference and import the namespace that defines this attribute:

```
`using System.ComponentModel;`
```

Comment: I did, but my project must compile using .net core, instead full .net framework