# MVC Html Helper DisplayName use

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

To my knowledge the html helper method  `DisplayNameFor` will take the value set in `Display` attributed decorating the property in the expression passed to it, so for example for the following property.

```
[Display(Name = "Name", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

If you have Resource entry as follows

```
Name: First Name
```

If you use DisplayNameFor as follows

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Name)
```

The displayed value will be

```
First Name
```

My question is, why don't you use the reference to the resource directly in razor so instead of using the `DisplayNameFor` method, you just use the follow

```
@Resource.Name
```

In my opinion this is even better because it doesn't have the risk of magic strings used in the `Display` attribute. So what value does `DisplayNameFor` add to my code? and why should I use it?

Comment: I think it is for localization.

Comment: Localization of DisplayNameAttribute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356464/localization-of-displaynameattribute

Comment: Yes I understand this, I have already mentioned this in the question, if it for localization, why don't we just write `@Resource.Name` instead of the `DisplayNameFor` , and avoid the risk of using magic strings the the `Display` attribute.

Comment: To avoid the use of the Display name attribute at all (and no magic strings), you can extend the framework - http://www.michael-whelan.net/using-humanizer-with-asp-dotnet-core/ That is .NET Core, but there is a way of doing it for MVC 5 as well. Inherit from DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider. Google that.